# validate the number of arguments passed to method/function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that in JavaScript that the best way to do overloading is to use the `arguments` object like this:

```
function myFunciton(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    switch(arguments.length) {
        case 3:
            // Do something with 3 args
            break;
        case 2:
            // Do something with 2 args
            break;
        case 1:
            // Do something with 1 args
            break;
        default:
            // Do something with no args
            break;
    }
}
```

With the above example, say you either need to pass `1 argument` or `all three arguments`, and two arguments are invalid. How would you define that within TypeScript, so that an error would be thrown if two arguments are attempted to be used?

I tried making an interface like this:

```
interface MyObject {
  myFunciton: (arg1: string) => this
  myFunciton: (arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number) => this
}
```

This however, gives the error:

> Duplicate identifier 'myFunction'.

Comment: with new es2015 spread syntax, you can turn the arguments to an Array and then check the length?

Comment: Yeah, I was going to do that, but how would I define the possible overloads?

Comment: Basically what I am looking for is a pre-processor solution so when TS compiles it throws errors if you use 1 argument (as in the example above) or an ide may underline it saying you can't use 1 argument

Comment: Why do you not check the arguments within the function body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, you define [overloads on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) by supplying multiple function types.

Your function would be written as:

```
function myFunction(arg1);
function myFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3);
function myFunction(arg1, arg2?, arg3?) {
    switch(arguments.length) {
        case 3:
            // Do something with 3 args
            break;
        case 2:
            // Do something with 2 args (TS won't allow this one)
            break;
        case 1:
            // Do something with 1 args
            break;
        default:
            // Do something with no args (TS won't allow this one)
            break;
    }
}
```

Your interface would be written as:

```
interface MyObject {
    myFunction(arg1: string): this;
    myFunction(arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number): this;
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for! I was just found that before you posted :) Thanks

Comment: Looks like I don't need to use an interface at all, it automatically picks it up